# Android Application user permission conflict with android aar library user permission

Tags: android, permissions, sdk, android-6.0-marshmallow, aar

**How do can we handle android(>=23) user permission, for the following situation.**

- I have created a AAR android library which uses locations/camera, implemented  runtime permission handling the locations/camera for the AAR lib.
- Above AAR library is included in a Android Application which uses the same permission like locations/camera, implemented the runtime permission for app.

--Now When the application is running, the user deny permission with never ask again option checked for both Android Application as well as android AAR library.

> - How can user enable the permission?
> - How to handle this issue in the android library?

Since when going to setting in the android device, if we allow location/camera permission only android application permission is getting enabled. The Android library permission is disabled completely.

Comment: detect this in the library. Show a message to the user indicating the app cannot work without this permission (if that is the case), and link to the system settings where the user can change the permissions

Comment: "How can user enable the permission?" -- through the Settings app. "if we allow location/camera permission only android application permission is getting enabled. The Android library permission is disabled completely." -- since that should be impossible, you might wish to explain, in detail, how you have come to that conclusion. The library is part of the app; the entire app, and all of its code, share the same permissions.

Comment: @njzk2- When we link the option to settings it will enable the locations/camera only for application user permission. The library aar user permission is not effected

Answer (score 1):

Providing run time permission check in a library is definitely not a good idea. It couples heavily app and its library. Suppose that you can only ask for permission in a library while you could not implement the callback to deal with it. So the app has to do this instead.

The best practice is to control the run time permission within app. While you can still use some other gentler way to mind the users or app developers that this library needs this permission, like dialog, toast, or even throw an exception in some certain cases.

In a word, the app should manage all the permissions it needs, not the library.